# Large Model Collections in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Whilst implementing my first MVVM application in WPF, I've been wondering about the pros and cons of wrapping Model collections in related ViewModel collections to use in the View.

In our system we are likely to have several potentially large collections e.g. Order Lines in an Order, and Stock Items which could be selected for an Order Line. At present these are looked up from SQL in the Data Access layer, and then SqlDataReaders are looped around to create a collection of Model Objects.

To then loop around the collection of Model objects when creating a collection of ViewModel objects seems like an unnecessary overhead. When there are large collections of Model objects would it be better to expose these directly on the View?

Thanks in advance for your help, Mark

---

**Edit**
While reading up on this subject I found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx) from July this year (reviewed by Josh Smith no less) which gives a pretty balanced view of MVVM, and in the 'Collections' section said this:

> Another problem with collections is
>   determining when or if to wrap each
>   Model instance in the collection
>   within a ViewModel instance. For
>   smaller collections, the ViewModel may
>   expose a new observable collection and
>   copy everything in the underlying
>   Model collection into the ViewModel
>   observable collection, wrapping each
>   Model item in the collection in a
>   corresponding ViewModel instance as it
>   goes. The ViewModel might need to
>   listen for collection-changed events
>   to transmit user changes back to the
>   underlying Model.
>
> However, for very large collections
>   that will be exposed in some form of
>   virtualizing panel, the easiest and
>   most pragmatic approach is just to
>   expose the Model objects directly.

Thanks very much for the comments so far, trying to limit the amount of data passed into the ViewModel, or using paginated or other suitable controls would reduce problems I'm sure, but I wonder if there would there still be situations where it would be better to simply bind to a collection of Model objects within the ViewModel?

Comment: Ted is my nickname view onto my real name model of Mark! (And this comment is the ViewModel?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it would really depend on how you want to go about displaying the data. Afterall the ViewModel is primarily there to handle the data that the View requires.

Assuming that your data layer provides you with just the data collections you could always restrict the creation of elements within the ViewModel depending on those that you actually want to see.

For example you may have a Datagrid to display Order Items for a given Order.

Thus you could have a ViewModel Property AllOrderItems bound to the datagrid and yet its getter is as follows:

```
public List<OrderItems> AllOrderItems
{
get{return this.DataAccessLayer.GetOrderItems().Where(x=>x.OrderNumber==this.OrderNumber).toList();
}
```

Here the DataAccessLayer is a class that holds cache database data and interfaces to the database. If kept as a singleton then data duplication within it will be reduced.

You can adapt your ViewModel to do as much or as little filtering of data from the DataAccessLayer as requried. The collections can be Observable if requried and the DataAccessLayer can generate events for VMs to react to for cases of new data being added, removed, saved to the database.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit on the slow side with finishing this query off! We've now completed this project, and thought i should get things tidied up. We did end up wrapping the model objects, and indeed did have speed issues when displaying lots of rows (50k +) in a datagrid, but as Chris, and a previous answerers pointed out, this isn't really a reasonable thing to expect the datagrid to handle without pagination. We set up filters to prevent users regularly returning this many rows, or at least to warn them that slow down may occur when certain filters were removed. Thanks for the input!